# Like a facebook page using ios 6.0 social api

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I want to implement like a page functionality using ios 6.0 social api. I think if I get exact Facebook Graph API link for like functionality then it possible. But I am not getting what's the exact url. Many are saying that it's not possible. I would like to know exact answer.

Please check and below code and response from Facebook.

```
{
    "error": {
        "message":"(#100) Like actions are not yet supported against objects of this type.",
        "type":"OAuthException",
        "code":100
    }
}
```

Code :

```
 NSURL *meurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes?"];
 NSDictionary *param = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:account.credential.oauthToken,@"access_token",@"https://www.facebook.com/sample",@"object", nil]; 
SLRequest *merequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:meurl parameters:param];
merequest.account = account;
[merequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",response);
}];
```

Comment: Have you resolved your problem? I would welcome the solution because I've just occured the same case.